# Jasmine Data Provider is not working (jasmine_data_provider_1.using is not a function)

Tags: javascript, typescript, jasmine, protractor, ui-automation

I am trying to achieve Data Driven testing in my project by using jasmine data providers.

I have a `data.ts` file like below

```
export const hardshipTestData = {

    scenarios: {

        scenario1: {
        isHome: 'Yes'
        },

        scenario2: {
            isHome: 'No'
        }

    }
};
```

I am using above data in spec file

```
import { using } from 'jasmine-data-provider';
import { hardshipTestData } from '../../data/testdata';

 using(hardshipTestData.scenarios, function (data, description) {
        it('testing data providers', () => {
            console.log(data.isHome);
        });
    });
```

My issue here is when I am trying to write `data.` intelligence is not even giving the option `isHome`. When I enforce it and run the test I am getting the following error

```
TestSuite encountered a declaration exception
configuration-parser.js:48
  - TypeError: jasmine_data_provider_1.using is not a function
```

any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change import type. Try to replace:

```
import { using } from 'jasmine-data-provider';
```

with:

```
const using = require('jasmine-data-provider');
```

Also, keep in mind that firstly should be `describe` block:

```
describe('example test', () => {
    using(hardshipTestData.scenarios, (data) => {
        it('should calc with operator -', () => {
            console.log(data.isHome);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for responding.

`import { using } from 'jasmine-data-provider';`

`const using = require('jasmine-data-provider');`

Can you explain to me the difference between import from and require. when do we use import from and when do we use require? little confused new to scripting.

Comment: it is different type of modules. Just type in google "Module types in js"

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Oleksii answer, his answer is for typescript.
but If you want to use in plain javascript use below:

Add below in your code:

```
var using = require('jasmine-data-provider');
```

Example:

```
var jasminedatasetobj = require("./jasmineDataDrivenData");
var using = require('jasmine-data-provider');

using(jasminedatasetobj.datadrive, function (data, description) {
it('Open NonAngular js website Alerts', async() => {


    await browser.get("https://qaclickacademy.github.io/protocommerce/");
    element(by.name("name")).sendKeys(data.name);

});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You might need to give full path of Jasmine data provider for plain javascripts to avoid module not found error.

```
  var jsondataobj = require('../../../../config/Jsoninput.json');//define  the data source location
    var using = require('C:/Users/sam/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/jasmine-data-provider'); 

    describe("Test Jasmine Data provider",function(){
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to declare the variable for "jasmine-data-provider" , because import can use to import the properties/classes. 
instead of using variable you can give any name to the varible (I tried use "post" instead of "using" and it is still working as expected)

your code should be like

```
import { hardshipTestData } from "../Test";

const using = require("jasmine-data-provider");

describe("Login TestCases", () => {
using(hardshipTestData.scenarios, (alldata: any, alldesc: any) => {
        it("login with different credentials", async () => {
 console.log(data.isHome);
})
})
})
```

this will resolve you problem.